# MATLAB: What is plotted on the x-axis?

Tags: matlab, plot, knn

weird question, but I am new to this. So we were asked to count all the occurrences when a frame contains a ball of a video and plot it (knn-nearest neighbor). So I looked through the material frame by frame and wrote all the occurrences for the different k-values in an excel chart. Now, I imported this dataset to Matlab and plotted it (as best as I could). However, I don't know what is plotted on the x-axis? Is this the time the ball occurs and y is the frames the ball occurs? [image: This is the graph that is plotted]

```
clc;
clear all;

k1 = xlsread('k1-5table.xlsx', 1, 'A2')
k2 = xlsread('k1-5table.xlsx', 1,'B2:B119')
k3 = xlsread('k1-5table.xlsx', 1, 'C2:C102')
k4 = xlsread('k1-5table.xlsx', 1, 'D2:D76')
k5 = xlsread('k1-5table.xlsx', 1, 'E2:E62')

plot(k1, 'r', 'LineWidth', 3)
hold on;
plot(k2, 'b')
hold on;
plot(k3, 'g')
hold on;
plot(k4, 'k')
hold on;
plot(k5, 'y')
xlabel('time per frame'), ylabel('frames')
title('k1-5 Difference')
legend('k1 = red', 'k2 = blue', 'k3 = green', 'k4 = black', 'k5 = yellow')
```

[image: And this is part of my Excel table, so for each K-kNN-Value one column]

thanks for your help, and sorry for my lack of knowledge here.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `plot`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)? `plot(Y) creates a 2-D line plot of the data in Y versus the index
 of each value. If Y is a vector, then the x-axis scale ranges from 1 to length(Y).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When plotting using plot(y) you get on the x-axis the indices of the vector y
: 1, 2, ..., length(y).